# HTML_Template_IT and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pear, template-engine

I want to use PEAR's HTML_Template_IT in one of my Wordpress page templates so I can separate the HTML from the PHP. I got it working, except I am not sure about one thing.

Wordpress's built-in function get_header() actually echo's HTML - so I can't technically set it as a template variable. Is this considered acceptable or is there another way to put the contents of get_header() in a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could do ob_start() to turn output buffering on, call the function, use ob_get_contents() to get the value that would be echoed and then use ob_end_clean() to erase the buffer and turn buffering off.

See [Output Buffering Control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Watch out for get_footer(),get_sidebar(),... They work the same way.

They are all handled by do_action()  .../wp-includes/plugin.php 
code: call_user_func_array($the_['function'],....)

Perhaps it's better to place you 'get html-code' there.
But watch out on WP-Updates.

Comment: So in other words, make these functions return the HTML instead of printing them out? That's actually a pretty good idea, but I'm not using the template engine on the entire site so it would break the regular functionality in other places.